# CodeIgniter: Is it possible to remove index.php without using .htaccess?

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, codeigniter-routing

For technical reasons, I don't want to use `.htaccess` to remove index.php from URL in CodeIgniter. I have seen the route section. I also tried with a route like this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'index.php/$1';
```

But it is not working.

Is it possible to remove `index.php` using the router in CodeIgniter?

Comment: yes you can using `routes`,it will still work, **BUT** `index.php` will still appear on the url, `htaccess` gives you the pretty url you want and removes the `index.php` on every request depending on what is defined on you're `htaccess` rules

Comment: What exactly is the technical limitation to which you're referring?

Comment: if i change the server or path then i need to change `RewriteBase` property in .htaccess. sometimes i dont have authority to change that :( @djthoms

Comment: thanks @tomexsans. Then i can not remove `index.php` from **URL** by routes? And my routes is not working. for example, i have a controller `home` and i will browse it like http://sitename/home. but it showing not found message. :(

Comment: you can't remove it from url without .htaccess, it is the entry point, actually .htaccess not remove it, just hide it from the url

Comment: removing the index.php from url can be done ONLY with htaccess

Comment: check my answer, you may not use .htaccess, then you will need a virtual host, or to edit your DNS to point to index.php ! its a server thing not php/framework thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Is it possible to remove index.php without using .htaccess?
```

**No. it is something beyond php or codeigniter, its a server thing.**

### Why ?

What happens when user try to go to `localhost/codeigniter/welcome/index` ?

MVC basically hide all your php files inside its folders. and present only one way for any user to interact with your code through `index.php`

what happen is

1. HTTP request to your website directed to index.php
2. index.php load codeigniter bootstrap and call codeigniter router
3. router look up the url typed (welcome/index) then go fetch the file welcome from inside controller folder and call index function.

**this is plain simple what all MVC frameworks do, hide your code and use a single front file to handle all requests and redirect them using a router class.**

so if you want to `hide` index.php then you need to find a way to tell your server to  simply redirect any call to index.php.

index.php is the access door for your website, and your server need to know that all requests must be sent to it. some way or another, and thats why index.php/ must exisit in ur url or use some server configuration to redirect calls to it. but it is always loaded

Comment: Answer is great, but not cleared. What actually do the CodeIgniter router? I have some apps with lots of custom routing using CodeIgniter router. Can you mention about why i can not remove `index.php` but others string from URL.

Comment: route is a class.. all it do is get PHP $_SERVER['url'] and explode it to find the correct controller. i think you are missing one thing.. every page you open in your codeigniter project is opened inside `index.php` .. `index.php` is the only public file. other files are Included inside `index.php`, so all your controllers etc are included `include('controller/welcome`)` inside index.php , and the class that handle this include.. is route class

Comment: Now i got your point, the router class is also inside index.php. After running `index.php`, the router class works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following to work with routes that do not require to have `index.php` in your url.

1. I have renamed `index.php` in `index_ci.php` for security reasons.
2. In `.htaccess` file I have the following:

   ```
   DirectoryIndex index_ci.php index.html
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index_ci\.php) # do not allow direct access  
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_ci.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   ```
3. My `routes.php` now accepts urls without `index.php` prefix. Example:

   ```
   $route['welcome'] = "welcome";
   ```

Comment: @lighta: reading his question the second I saw what you said :D

Comment: @machineaddict: thanks. but i can do it with .htaccess, i just need to know the way of without using .htaccess and only with CodeIgniter router :)

Comment: There is just not possible. It doesn't matter if its CodeIgniter, other framework or pure php scripts. Url rewrite happens at apache level, you cannot do it in php.